# Create an array in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I need to create a new array from other one dimensional array in smarty template.
So, what are the best possibilities to create an array in template file.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 33):

Smarty3 allows you to `{$var = ['foo' => 'bar', 'sub' => [1, 2, 3]]}` and `{$var.foo = 'other'}`

if those options don't suffice, write a [plugin function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl).

Comment: I have tried this advice and it works. This feature does not appear to be documented in Smarty documentation, which makes this advice even more valuable to me.

Answer (score 14):

It's actually very simple:

```
{assign 'myArray' ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']}
```

Comment: Does it work with version 2 ?

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 13):

In the past, I have used two approaches - an evil and a dirty one - to quickly assign an array inside a tpl:

```
{* Am I evil? *}
{php}
    $array = array("cat", "dog", "rabbit");
    $this->assign("myArray", $array);
{/php}

{* Am I dirty? *}
{assign var='myArray' value=','|explode:"cat,dog,rabbit"}
```

Both result in your array available inside the template to build a simple loop. Anyway I always ended up changing my code this way, so I did not need this stuff at all.

Comment: I don't like the first approach, because of "inline" php code. The second solution is a bit tricky but is still valid smarty without any hacks. Voted up!

Comment: and it works with smarty-v2!

Answer (score 1):

I advise against this but this plugin allows this: http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=set

Answer (score 1):

From a MVC point of view, the View part of it is only responsible with displaying the data. I would encourage you to rethink the application in such a way that it will allow you to process the data in the Model and pass it for display only in the View.

Comment: And how do you process a table (with rows) in a Model so that there wouldn't be any HTML markup? You still have to pass whole array of data and build dynamic table from it in the view.

Comment: @Andrew Am I missing something in my answer? I didn't say the view has to be static, I only pointed out that all the data processing should be done in the model and passed to the view to be displayed.

Comment: Catalin> Yeah, i understand what you mean. I just wanted to know if there is a way to prevent loop in template. And AFAIK there isn't any...

Comment: @Andrew well you could but it wouldn't be effective. You could for example loop a function which renders only one row of the table or something like that.