# SMARTY: How to populate a new array from database foreach loop

Tags: php, smarty

[Create an array in smarty template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929140/create-an-array-in-smarty-template)
 This does not answer my question. I have a list that I am retrieving from the database using a `PHP` class and in the template, I have a foreach loop.

What I want to do is create a list from the data retrieved from the database.
This what I have.

```
{assign list=[]}
{foreach from=$prescriptions item=prescription}
    {$list[]=$prescription->drug}
    {$prescription->drug|escape:'html'}
{/foreach}
{$list|print_r}<--- Really not needed as the above prints to the screen.
```

What's happening is the data is not being appended to the list. It is overwriting the last entry with each pass of the loop.

What I want is the list to be a string drug1,drug2,drug3,drug(n).

Now I get an error message.

> /templates/prescription/general_list.html line 150]: syntax error:
>   unrecognized tag: $list[]=$prescription->drug

Can't seem to find the right syntax for adding values to the array.

Comment: Can't you do this in php file? It is rather an application logic and shouldn't be put into a template. If it has to be in the template, you could try using function `append` [link](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.append.tpl)

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I end up moving the logic to the controller and sending the results to the display as a constant.